# What is the meaning of the word مريب in Surah qaf, Ayah 25?

Tags: quran, arabic-translation

> أَلْقِيَا فِي جَهَنَّمَ كُلَّ كَفَّارٍ عَنِيدٍ مَّنَّاعٍ لِّلْخَيْرِ مُعْتَدٍ **مُّرِيبٍ**
>
> *[ Allah will say], "Throw into Hell every obstinate disbeliever, preventer of good, aggressor, and doubter [Quran 50:24-25]*

This is the Sahih International translation of Surah qaf, Ayahs 24-25. But another translations says:

> *"Cast, you both, in (to) Hell every stubborn, most disbelieving (one), (All) persistent preventers of charity, transgressors, (and the ones) causing suspicion" [Quran 50:24-25]*

I'm confused about the word **مريب** so if you speak Arabic, please help me out. Does it mean "one who has doubts" or does it mean "one who causes doubts in others"? Or is it both? I'm confused.

According to one website, it means one who is "not only himself involved in doubt but also created doubts in the hearts of others". Do you guys agree?

http://www.islamicstudies.info/tafheem.php?sura=50&verse=16

Answer (score 1):

From a dictionary:

> مريب: doubtful ; dubious ; dubitable ; equivocal ; fishy ; open to doubt or question ; questionable ; suspicious (source: [almaany](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A8/))

And from Tafsir like ibn Kathir:

> مُرِيبٍ 
>   (doubter,) meaning, he doubts and raises doubts in those who scrutinize his behavior, ([qtafsir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1728&Itemid=106))

Imam al-Qurtoby in [his tafsir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=48&surano=50&ayano=25) said that it refers to people who have doubt in the unity of Allah (this was quoted by al-Hassan and Qatadah) therefore Allah says in the next verse ([50:26](http://legacy.quran.com/50/26))

> **Who made [as equal] with Allah another deity;** ...

[Imam at-Tabary](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=50&surano=50&ayano=25) said about the same:

> وقوله ( مريب ) يعني : شاك في وحدانية الله وقدرته على ما يشاء .
>
> who doubts in Allah'S unity and HIS power or aptitude to do whatever HE wants

Also according at-Tabari: Qatadah said مُرِيبٍ  means who doubts!

Ibn Achour in his [tahrir wa tanwir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=61&surano=50&ayano=25) said:

> والمريب الذي أراب غيره ، أي جعله مرتابا ، أي شاكا ، أي بما يلقونه إلى الناس من صنوف المغالطة ليشككوهم في صدق الرسول صلى الله عليه وسلم وصحة الإيمان والتوحيد .
>
> ...المريب is the person who make other people doubt or raise doubts in them by telling them fallacies to create doubts in the truth or sincerity of the Prophet () and the justness of faith and unity.

So yes its also a person who creates doubts in the hearts of others!

Comment: But what if a muslim starts having doubts about the unity of Allah but instead if acting on it, he ignores the doubt and he continues to pray salah to Allah only?

Comment: @curiosity this IMO is a new Question, for which i have no answer right now :)

Answer (score 0):

My brother, as in the Arabic Tafser, مريب means *someone who has a doubt in his heart about Islam*.  And maybe it can mean as in the link that you have shared.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I strongly invite you to take some time to learn more about this site and our model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help].